# Getting an error when pulling code from git

Tags: git

Getting this error when i try to pull the latest code from the server :

```
Fetch failed
                error: inflate: data stream error (unknown compression method)
                error: unable to unpack bd808e4d3216bcf22641e082379db122859b367b header
                fatal: SHA1 COLLISION FOUND WITH bd808e4d3216bcf22641e082379db122859b367b !
                fatal: index-pack failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Check first if the issue persists when:

- using the latest Git version
- and cloning the repo again (instead of pulling)

Then, following "[git fatal: SHA1 COLLISION FOUND](http://SHA1%20COLLISION%20FOUND%20WITH)", try:

```
git prune
git gc
```

(to see if any error message pops up)

---

If you have changes, you can easily integrate them back to a new clone:

```
git clone /url/repo newfolder
cd newfolder
git --work-tree=/path/to/old/folder add .
git commit -m "import work in progress"
```

Comment: i tried that, and deleted 2 files which showed erorr. but now getting this error which does not define which file is being deleted. error : warning: reflog of 'HEAD' references pruned commits
warning: reflog of 'refs/heads/master' references pruned commits
warning: reflog of 'refs/remotes/origin/master' references pruned commits
error: Could not read c51a32f3856b20c13bb23006d6e0ff1a84d2e092
fatal: bad tree object c51a32f3856b20c13bb23006d6e0ff1a84d2e092

Comment: Note: I very much doubt this is a shattered.io -type of SHA1 collision I detailed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/42450327/6309.

Comment: @ParthAnjaria What cloning again (in another local folder) would yield?

Comment: ill try that now, but in that case ill have to add my changes manually to the new project, i wanted to avoid that, so as last resort i tried asking the question here.

Comment: @ParthAnjaria Do you mean work in progress not yet committed? Or multiple local commits not yet pushed?

Comment: work was commited and pushed in one PC. now in other PC i am trying to update the code and pulling it from the server, so getting this issue

Comment: @ParthAnjaria in that case, no problem: your clone will download the commits pushed from one PC. All you need to do, after the clone, is to checkout the branch you were working on: if those commits were pushed form one PC, you will find them in your clone.