# Is git ls-tree blob sha not unique?

Tags: git

I always thought that every single git object has a unique sha. Then, when I was listing a git tree, I found this:

```
...
100644 blob fc47072354934eb062321af9d1c4897244562b67    exp2f-inputs
100644 blob fc47072354934eb062321af9d1c4897244562b67    expf-inputs
...
100644 blob 7eb7bda5e433f5df0fd6fec001c69cab7a08ebdb    fmaxf-inputs
...
100644 blob 7eb7bda5e433f5df0fd6fec001c69cab7a08ebdb    fminf-inputs
...
100644 blob 50a97394769447a692318ccefe333b494da7cc97    log2f-inputs
100644 blob 50a97394769447a692318ccefe333b494da7cc97    logf-inputs
...
```

Those files are from [glibc](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree;f=benchtests;h=d4f70e6437f85daf3a3194f35cfee61ef05af91b;hb=HEAD).

My question is, are those `sha` not supposed to be unique for every single git object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every single [Git object](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) *does* have a unique SHA. That tree object you're listing contains multiple references to the same blob object.

A blob object is, basically, the contents of a file. Those two files have the same contents, so Git stores them as the same blob.

```
$ echo 'basset hounds got long ears' > file1
$ cp file1 file2
$ git hash-object -t blob file1 file2
a55bd80950a2a5fc0b43b76ec1b3da190efcd212
a55bd80950a2a5fc0b43b76ec1b3da190efcd212
```

Here's an illustration of the relationship between tree and blob objects from the [Git Objects chapter of the Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects).

[image]

That's how this file tree is stored...

```
new.txt       "new file"
test.txt      "version 2"
bak/
    test.txt  "version 1"
```

Incidentally, this is how Git can store complete snapshots of every file at each commit efficiently. Since each commit usually only changes a few files, commits mostly reference the same tree and blob objects.

Comment: So, I can't rely on those SHA's to uniquely identify blobs?

Comment: @MasBagol You can! But you have to recognize what a blob is. It's just the content of the file. The filename (and I think permissions) are stored in the tree. This is analogous to how a filesystem works, directories and inodes.

Comment: "Unique" modulo collisions.

Comment: @Schwern I see. So a blob is not file, and a blob is just the content of file(s), am I correct? If so, can those SHA's used to uniquely identify files?

Comment: @MasBagol: you'll have to define what *you* mean by "file" here. This question is more subtle than it looks at first! Is `foo.ext` the same file as `bar.txt`? What if I've run `mv foo.ext bar.txt`? (Compare with the philosophical question of [the Ship of Theseus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus).)

Comment: @Jubobs Non-engineered collisions are astronomically unlikely and [how Git handles them is well understood](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392365/how-would-git-handle-a-sha-1-collision-on-a-blob#34599081).

Comment: @MasBagol I think it would be best if you backed up and told us what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: What I try to accomplish is like to make a flat JSON map of git tree. And I was using those SHA as key which is doesn't work if it's not unique.

Comment: @MasBagol In that case do what a tree object does. For a file the key is the filename and the value is the blob ID. For a directory, the key is the directory name and the file is another tree.