# using Go linter with security issue

Tags: security, go, lint

we use the following lib

`import "crypto/sha1"`

while running golangci-lint we got the following errors :

```
G505: Blocklisted import crypto/sha1: weak cryptographic primitive (gosec) for "crypto/sha1"


 G401: Use of weak cryptographic primitive (gosec)
        sha := sha1.New()
```

Is there is something that I can do without excluding them? not sure that I understand those issues. if it was not related to security it's simple tasks to exclude ...

**update**

**what we are doing is**

```
fdrContent, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filepath.Join(path))
// gets the hashcode of the FDR file
h := sha1.New()
code, err := h.Write(fdrContent)
return code, err
```

Comment: Check why you are using it and whether security is a concern for that specific use case. If it is, use something else. Without more info, we can't tell.

Comment: @Marc - but Im not sure what is the problem, I need to know it before Im changing to something else :)

Comment: The problem is that `sha1` is considered pretty broken (see the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) for a brief overview of attacks). If you're using it for anything sensitive, stop. If you want our opinion, you'll need to tell us what you're using it for.

Comment: @Marc - please see my update

Comment: Ok, so you're calculating the hash of a file. Is it to verify its integrity, or something like duplicate file checks? If the former, stop using `sha1`, collisions have been found meaning someone could make another file with the same hash. Please elaborate on the use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `h.Write` in my own [`gtarsum` project](https://github.com/VonC/gtarsum) as [in here](https://github.com/VonC/gtarsum/blob/3546e8285edf517655e936b87d241d37cf90b3ef/main.go#L126-L138):

```golang
        h := sha256.New()
        for {
            buf := make([]byte, 1024*1024)

            bytesRead, err := tr.Read(buf)
            if err != nil {
                if err != io.EOF {
                    panic(err)
                }
            }

            if bytesRead > 0 {
                _, err := h.Write(buf[:bytesRead])
```

All you have to do, if there is no obvious performance issue, is to switch to [sha256](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/sha256/).
No more warning.
The issue comes sha1 collision, that I have [documented here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42450327/6309), from the [**`shattered.io`**](https://shattered.io/) project.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what in the question indicates that this is using `cloudfoundry/capi-release`?

Comment: @Marc This is just one project which has a similar issue. I have removed that reference to avoid any confusion.

Comment: From OP's clarification, it's clear this has nothing to do with cloud foundry. The question is not about how to ignore the check, it's about whether they should.

Comment: @Marc This is about where that warning is coming from, which is exactly what my answer addresses.

Comment: Any project using `sha1` and running this linter will encounter the same warning. Whether they should do anything about it is another question entirely (and the one relevant here).

Comment: Please read the question again. OP understands where the warning comes from, they are just unsure about the right course of action.

Comment: @Marc Right. Answer rewritten accordingly.