# git-filter-repo callback commit or callback message and --preserve-commit-hashes not working?

Tags: git, commit, commit-message, git-filter-repo

I'm trying to update commit messages but on same time to keep the same hash.

i try both options --message-callback and --commit-callback but no mater which one i choose, it generates new hashes.
Here how i do that:

```
python3 git-filter-repo.py --preserve-commit-hashes --message-callback (or --commit-callback) '
if b"blabla" not in message:
    message = b"MyMessage " + message
return message' --force
```

Is this a kind of bug? Or i do something completely wrong?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'm trying to update commit messages but on same time to keep the same hash.

This is not possible.  The hash is a cryptographic checksum of the *entire content* of the commit.  Changing a single bit in the *message* has the same radical effect on the checksum as changing a single bit in the timestamp: the new commit gets a new, unique hash ID.  This is how other Git commands (on any computer) recognize that this is not the *same commit* as the original commit.  If the hash *didn't* change, you would not be able to store the updated commit, nor send it to any other Git.

This is a fundamental concept at the heart of the storage model for Git: that the hash ID *is* the object.  The [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) be damned, every bitstream *must* have its own unique hash ID.  If you can [break the hash function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42433126/1256452), you can [break—or at least stymie—progress in the repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9392365/1256452).

(The `--preserve-commit-hashes` option makes the built in default message rewrite option not look for patterns that resemble commit hash IDs, look them up in the translation table that filter-repo generates, and use the result.  This is the opposite of what you'd want with a repository in which there was extensive use of `git cherry-pick -x`, where each cherry-picked commit would say something about it being a cherry pick of previous commit *H*, for some hash.  The filter-repo program tries to make sure the earlier commits are handled first, and then replace the outdated hash ID in the subsequent commits.  I have no idea how well this works in practice: the goal is obvious but the details get pretty sticky.  I'm not entirely sure why this option exists at all, but if you're doing a history rewrite and some things that resemble commit hashes, but aren't actually commit hashes, are being damaged, that would probably be why you would use this option.)